# All in one HTTPS htaccess redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I've searched the net and Stack overflow, and it seems like there are many answers to parts of this question but no overarching solution.

What I really need is .htacccess code that does ALL of the following.

PLEASE NOTE: Spaces added to get around a links limitation in Stack overflow, so disregard the spaces in the domains.

-- 1 --

Redirects a top level primary domain.

**http:// domain.com to https:// domain.com**

**http:// www.domain.com to https:// domain.com**

-- 2 --

And also redirects subfolders/pages to the https equivalent.

**http:// domain.com/example/test to https:// domain.com/example/test**

-- 3 --

And finally also redirects a possible secondary domain.

**http:// domaintwo.com to https:// domain.com**

**http:// domaintwo.com/example/test to https:// domaintwo.com/example/test**

**http:// www.domaintwo.com to https:// domain.com**

**http:// www.domaintwo.com/example/test to https:// domain.com/example/test**

If I could get the answer to this that would be AWESOME!

Thank you!

Anthony

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain\.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule ^ https://domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```